# Terminology: group action with normal stabilizers

Tags: gr.group-theory, terminology

This is just a terminology question. Is there a name for a group action which is transitive and for which the stabilizers are normal subgroups?

In this situation, the stabilizers are all equal. If the group is $G$ and $N$ is the stabilizer, the action is essentially the regular action of $G/N$, but turned into an action of $G$ using $G \to G/N$.

In a paper I'm currently writing, these actions show up quite a lot (they are the "boring" actions, in a certain context anyway). It's just tedious to write "the stabilizers are normal".

I'm considering the possibility of calling them "normal actions", but the word "normal" is used so often in mathematics that I'm not sure. Or maybe "almost regular", "quasi-regular" ? My co-author informally calls them "regular with a kernel", but that's confusing and not very short.

*Edit:* I should have added that I'm also, and perhaps mainly, looking for a name for actions which are transitive but NOT of this kind. Half jokingly, I'm thinking of calling them *abnormal*. This has the advantage that (1) there's no risk of confusing the name for something else, and (2) I think it makes it clear that I'm not suggesting a widespread adoption of the term, I just need a short phrase to use in this one paper.

Comment: For an action of a group $G$ on a nonempty set, if all stabilizers are equal, the common stabilizer is a normal subgroup $N$ and the $G/N$-action on the set is free. I find "almost regular/free" not too bad (maybe "relatively free"), but "normal action" counterintuitive. I agree that "regular with a kernel" is confusing.

Comment: You could also say "inflated regular" (inflated from $G/N$ back to $G$).

Comment: Or "image regular" because it is the image of the action that is regular.

Comment: How about calling it a "maximal core permutation action"?